# what is the time complexity of unordered_set<int>::iterator it+n?

Tags: c++, time-complexity

Suppose I have an `std::unordered_set<int>` named as `myset` and I want to return a random number from `myset` in `O(1)` time. I first use `rand()` to generate a random number as:

```
int n = rand() %  myset.size();
```

Then, I do:

```
myset.begin() + n;
```

I would like to know if `myset.begin() + n` is in `O(n)` or `O(1)`?

Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31113618/493106 states that, at least in GCC, it maintains a linked list across the entries, so it would be O(n) - though as ash said, not sure you can anctually use operator+ on the iterator.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `std::unordered_set<>::iterator` (which results from `myset.begin()`) is a `Constant ForwardIterator`. [Ref](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set)

A [ForwardIterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/ForwardIterator) supports incrementation (`++myIterator`) but not random incrementation, unlike the [RandomAccessIterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/RandomAccessIterator).

Therefore `myset.begin() + n` is not guaranteed to compile by the standard. It doesn't compile [here](http://ideone.com/14OZAe).

You can do the `++` incrementation `n` times with a loop, but then of course, complexity is at least O(n).

Comment: To add to your answer, [std::next](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/next) would be the right choice to get an iterator as required by the statement `myset.begin() + n` i.e. `std::next( myset.begin(), n )`. Example: http://ideone.com/so0XEH.

Comment: @Azeem good addition thanks. `std:next` takes a `ForwardIterator` so its internal implementation is likely a similar loop when such iterator that does not support random access. Should be the case for `unordered_set` in most implementations, but exceptions are theoretically possible.