# How data stored/How can we fetch data stored in bucket in unordered_map c++11

Tags: c++, c++11

I just wanted to how unordered map stored the data into the bucket and what hashing function it is implementing.Also the internal implementation of Hashing function i wanted to know in C++.How data is stored on what basis?
Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31112852/how-stdunordered-map-is-implemented

Comment: the standard for `std::unordered_map` doesn't specify a way to access buckets, only individual elements.

Comment: @vu1p3n0x Yes and no. See the "Bucket interface" section [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map).

Comment: @Angew wow, you're right! shows how much I use `unordered_map`s

Answer (score 2):

Different implementations of the standard library can use different hashing algorithms, storage details etc. Since the code invovles templates, most (if not all) standard library implementations contain the relevant code in headers. So you can just open the `<unordered_map>` header shipped in your standard library and start looking.

Comment: But if i see like the internal implementation of this can't able to understand it .So if i write a simple program for the same and get it the bucket stored data internally how it is doing then only i can get to know.                                            nordered_map<std::string,std::string> mymap = {
            {"Shashi","Singh"},
            {"Sumit","Arora"},
            {"Kunal","Yadav"},
            {"Bhargavi","Boddapati"},
            {"Biplab","Kundu"},
            {"Satyaraj","Natarajan"}
  }; ....now please tell me how it is sored in bucket Please :)

Comment: @shashisingh You **don't** use the internal implementation. You use the public members. **Especially** if you don't understand the contents of `<unordered_map>`

Comment: @shashisingh I'm confused. Either you're after the implementation details (as your question seems to indicate), in which case study the implementation (and you will of course need sufficient C++ and data structure understanding). Or you want to know how to *use* an unordered map, in which case consulting suitable [reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) should work for you.