# Why is vector faster than unordered_map?

Tags: c++, algorithm, dictionary, vector, unordered-map

I am solving a problem on LeetCode, but nobody has yet been able to explain my issue.

### The problem is as such:

Given an arbitrary ransom note string and another string containing letters from all the magazines, write a function that will return true if the ransom note can be constructed from the magazines ; otherwise, it will return false.

Each letter in the magazine string can only be used once in your ransom note.

Note:
You may assume that both strings contain only lowercase letters.

```
canConstruct("a", "b") -> false
canConstruct("aa", "ab") -> false
canConstruct("aa", "aab") -> true
```

#### My code (which takes 32ms):

```
class Solution {
public:
    bool canConstruct(string ransomNote, string magazine) {
        if(ransomNote.size() > magazine.size()) return false;
        unordered_map<char, int> m;
        
        for(int i = 0; i < magazine.size(); i++)
            m[magazine[i]]++;
            
        for(int i = 0; i < ransomNote.size(); i++)
        {
            if(m[ransomNote[i]] <= 0) return false;
            m[ransomNote[i]]--;
        }
        return true;
    }
};
```

#### The code (which I dont know why is faster - takes 19ms):

```
bool canConstruct(string ransomNote, string magazine) {
        int lettersLeft = ransomNote.size(); // Remaining # of letters to be found in magazine
        int arr[26] = {0};
        for (int j = 0; j < ransomNote.size(); j++) {
            arr[ransomNote[j] - 'a']++; // letter - 'a' gives a value of 0 - 25 for each lower case letter a-z
        }
        
        int i = 0;
        while (i < magazine.size() && lettersLeft > 0) {
            if (arr[magazine[i] - 'a'] > 0) {
                arr[magazine[i] - 'a']--;
                lettersLeft--;
            }
            i++;
        }
        if (lettersLeft == 0) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Both of these have the same complexity and use the same structure to solve the problem, but I don't understand why one takes almost twice as much time than the other. The time to query a vector is O(1), but its the same for an unordered_map. Same story with adding an entry/key to either of them.

Please, could someone explain why the run time varies so much?

Comment: The gist of it is, computers are really really fast with sequential memory. Cache lines, prefetching, vectorization are terms to look up. Big O notation measures growth, not actual values. Things like O(n) beat out O(1) a lot when N is small.

Comment: The second one doesn't have any vectors, but it does have an array...

Comment: @Shawn same story though. Its faster than the unordered_map. I got the answer though, thanks! :D

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First thing to note is, although the average time to query an `unordered_map` is constant, the worst case is not `O(1)`. As you can see [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_map/unordered_map/find/) it actually rises to the order of `O(N)`, `N` denoting the size of the container.

Secondly, as `vector` allocates sequential portions of memory, accessing to that memory is highly efficient and actually *is* constant, even in the worst-case. (i.e. simple pointer arithmetic, as opposed to computing the result of a more complex hash function) There is also the possibility of various levels of caching of sequential memory that may be involved (i.e. depending on the platform your code is running on) which may make the execution of a code using `vector` even faster, compared to one that is using `unordered_map`.

In essence, in terms of complexity, the worst-case performance of a `vector` is more efficient than that of `unordered_map`. On top of that, most hardware systems offer features such as caching which give usage of `vector` an even bigger edge. (i.e. lesser constant factors in `O(1)` operations)

Comment: you only answered why it is faster for lookups in `vector`. But the implementation is indeed `unordered_map(insert + lookup)` vs `array(lookup + allcoate 26-size array)`. For the logic point of view, it could also be the reason : insert for `unordered_map` takes longer that makes `un.*_map` seems less efficient.

Answer (score 4):

Your second approach uses plain C array where accessing an element is a simple pointer dereference. But that is not the case with `unordered_map`. There are two points to note:

1. First, accessing an element is not a simple pointer dereference. It has to do other works to maintain it's internal structure. An `unordered_map` is actually a hash table under the hood and C++ standard indirectly mandates [it to be implemented using open addressing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31112852/how-stdunordered-map-is-implemented) which is a far more complex algorithm than simple array access.
2. Second, O(1) access is on average but not on worst case.

For these reasons no wonder that array version will work better than `unordered_map` even though they have same run time complexity. This is another example where two codes with same run time complexity performs differently.

You will see the benefit of `unordered_map` only when you have a large number of keys (oppose to fixed 26 here).

Answer (score 1):

"O(1)" means "constant time" -- that is, an algorithm that is (truly) O(1) will not get slower when there is more data (in this case, when there are more items in the map or array).  It does not indicate how fast the algorithm runs -- it only indicates that it won't slow down if there is more data.  Seeing different times for one O(1) algorithm vs. another does not mean that they are not O(1).  You should not expect that one O(1) algorithm will run exactly as fast as another.  But, if there is a difference, you should see the same difference if the maps/arrays have more data in them.